# Do I have a personal blog "space" on SO or SE?

Tags: support

I remember some announcement from a while back about discontinuing something about blogs, but I couldn't find it. If I remember correctly, users were able to post on a (personal) blog provided by SE. Was I imagining? Is there anything of this sort currently available?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291741/273503

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If I remember correctly, users were able to post on a (personal) blog provided by SE

No - that was never a thing.

> Was I imagining?

Possibly - but what we did have were blogs for Stack Exchange **sites**. So topical blogs for certain of sites in the network (basically - those who wanted one).

---

> Is there anything of this sort currently available?

No, and I don't expect there will ever be.